# auto type specifier ignores top-level const

Tags: c++, c++11

I stumbled upon this question while reading "C++ Primer", by Lippman et al. (5/e)

```
 14     int i = 0;
 15     const int ci = i, &cr = ci;
 16     auto c = cr;
 17
 18     c = 12; // works fine
```

we have this code snippet.

in line 15
`const` on `ci` is top-level, `const` on `cr` is (as is always on references) is low-level.

Pg. 69 of this book goes to say,

"auto ordinarily ignores top-level consts"

But it is ignoring low-level `const` on `cr` as `c` is of type `int` (value of c can be changed to 12 without compiler complaining).
Whereas I expected `c` to be of the type `const int` as there is a low-level `const` on cr.

Please help me understand this.

Answer (score 0):

Think of the top-level as it relates to the resulting type of the `auto` variable.  If it was going to be `const int` it instead will be `int`.

If it was going to be `const int* const` it instead will be `const int*`.

Answer (score 0):

In simple terms, the top level `const` is the one that applies to the object itself. A `int * const` is not `const`, it is a non-const pointer to a `const`, whereas a top level `const` as in `const int * const` makes the object itself `const`.

The rules are designed to be useful. Removing the top most `const` makes `auto` applicable in such common cases:

```
const int x = 5;
auto y = x;
++y;
```

Usually C++ defaults to non-const. You need to specifiy it when you want to declare `y` as `const`.